# DNN WebResource.axd not found for custom control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, dotnetnuke, webresource.axd

I've build a custom control and want to add an embedded js file to it. I think I did everything right and the controls compiles like expected.

I've marked the js file to Build Action "Embedded Resource"

The simplified control:

```
[assembly: WebResource("GoogleMapsLegend.js", "application/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)] 
namespace CustomControls
{
    public class GoogleMapsLegend : WebControl
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(CustomControls.GoogleMapsLegend), "GoogleMapsLegend", Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(CustomControls.GoogleMapsLegend), "GoogleMapsLegend.js")); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the control in a DotNetNuke environment I get a 404

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
>   http://testenvironment.dev.nl/WebResource.axd?d=9ubkUMGTBWycKhgQIG5UHmzbPQjp5hcuPdO…jQr5YlIXdwqph6fJIVdtyKxWHJnyuIP44D9akltG8kiDFVFdwSND0&t=635122452802549563

Are there additional setting I need to put in the web.config?

I've tried adding the following to the web.config, but no luck so far.

```
<add verb="*" path="WebResource.axd" validate="true" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" />
```

Is it possible there's a conflict with the Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but it looks like the line you are using to register the script may be wrong.
If I am correct where you have "GoogleMapsLegend.js" you need the namespace/path before it

So if the file is in a subdirectory like 'JavaScript' then I think that should read

"Namespace.Javascript.GoogleMapsLegend.js"

I may be wrong here but I have used this article in the past for this: http://weblogs.asp.net/briandukes/archive/2009/06/08/embedding-javascript-and-other-resources-in-a-net-assembly.aspx

Comment: Works perfectly! Don't know it it's the namespace or the RegisterClientScriptResource instead of RegisterClientScriptInclude but it works now. Thanks!